# why .bss explicitly initialize global variable to zero?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, mips

I am generating mips disassembly in order to simulating it. I need to have big data to work on it but I don't want to have big assembly files so I wanted to work on a big uninitialized array (and then possibly initialize it in my simulator...). So I need this array to be global. And global variables seem to be put on the .bss section to be initialized when the page is actually accessed. 
The problem is in my binary the array is in the .bss section, but is explicitly filled with zero...This is not the behaviour expected if I understood correctly what I have found on internet...Is there a way for saying to the compiler (or linker, or loader...I don't understand well which one do what for that) to not really put zero in this array ?
Or alternatively, can we have an option while compiling, or a C instruction for saying we don't want this array for being initialized with 0 ? (I tried to change the array section with **attribute** but it is still initialized with 0).

By the way, I am generating my disassembly file with objdump, and it normally skip blocks of zeroes, but I really need the other blocks of zeroes to be disassembled, so I using the "-z" option.

What I really don't understand is that everywhere I looked, it was said that .bss section didn't really put zero in the binary file...

Comment: Perhaps your OS is initializing the bss section to zero when it loads the memory. Are you sure the binary image has the zeros in it?

Comment: At one time, bss would normally be allocated as un-initialized memory, but as a security measure, most OSes now initialize it to zero, so you can't even hope to run one program that might work with sensitive data, then run another that just allocates a big chunk of uninitialized storage in the hope of finding that sensitive data still in the memory.

Comment: thank you I didn't think answers will come so quikly ! 

mark ransom : I don't execute the executable, I just disassemble it with objdump...So it can't be when loading it from memory isn't it ?

jerry coffin : I see...So there is nothing we can do for that ? But if I just use a no uninitialized pointer I can read everywhere I want isn't it ?

Comment: Instead of using `objdump` you could use the `-S` option to gcc. This produces the assembler directly with the advantage that it might be more readable because you have less loss of information.

Comment: I use objdump in order to don't have to link myself the files...I was told it was pretty much easier in this way

Answer (score 9):

The data for the .bss section isn't stored in the compiled object files because, well, there is no data—the compiler puts variables in that segment precisely *because* they should be zero-initialized.

When the OS loads the executable, it just looks at the size of the .bss segment, allocates that much memory, and zero-initializes it for you.  By not storing that data in the executable file, it reduces loading times.

If you want data to be initialized with certain data, then give it an initializer in your code.  The compiler will then put it in the .data segment (initialized data) instead of .bss (uninitialized data).  When the OS then loads the executable, it will allocate the memory for the data and then copy it in from the executable.  This takes extra I/O, but your data is explicitly initialized how you want it.

Alternatively, you could leave the data stay in the .bss segment and then initialize it yourself at runtime.  If the data is quick and easy to generate at runtime, it might be faster to recompute it at startup rather then read it off of disk.  But those situations are probably rare.

Comment: Even if the data is fast to regenerate, it's a bad idea to generate constant tables at runtime. If the constant table is stored in the program binary, it's read-only and backed by a file on disk, so it doesn't consume commit charge and under memory pressure, it can just be discarded (no cost) and later reloaded (low cost) rather than having to be written out to swap (high cost) before being discarded.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I think you misunderstood my question...I have found on internet several posts that said what you say but my problem is that in fact, the data in the .bss section are actually stored in the executable file (or at lest the disassembly file)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that using the `-z` option is causing `objdump` to show you zeroes for the `.bss`, even though the zeroes are not actually in your binary. Try using `od -t x4` to get a simple hexadecimal dump of what is really in the binary.  If `od` shows you blocks of zeroes, then they really are in the binary.

Comment: I have done as you said but I don't understand well od output...It seems to have data in different addresses than objdump. And it put some * sometimes in places that have zeroes before and after...So I'm not sure it show all the data. But the fact that I don't use a tool from my cross compiler maybe have an influence...
Anyway, thank you for your help, but in fact I have found a way to resolve my problem : I put my array alone in a section I have created and I don't disassemble this section...